# Calling web service with current users credentials from SharePoint

Tags: .net, web-services, iis, credentials, impersonation

When I run this C# code from my vs2010 client it works authenticating as me.

However if I deploy the code to a sharePoint page on a webserver I get an authentication error from the web service.

I understand this some double hop issue and I need to impersonate. maybe the code is calling the web service as the SharePoint service user.

Any easy way around this beyond hard coding credentials?

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://tempuri.org/"); 
ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; 
NetworkCredential credential = credentials.GetCredential(uri, "Basic"); 
Service service = new Service("https://xxx/Exchange.asmx", credential);
```

Someone suggested using windowsidentity class with impersonate, but not sure how to plug that in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trusted to use the application pool identity to interact with your remote web service then you can use this technique:

http://mindsharpblogs.com/todd/archive/2005/05/03/467.html